# Can you change classes in the middle of a Battlefield 4 game?

Tags: battlefield-4

So I've never played BF4 before, but I had played a lot of CoD before. I only know a couple of things about BF4, like it has bigger maps and bullet-drop. One thing I would like to know is can I change classes mid-game? Are there even classes? I want to practice sniping, but if I start getting destroyed I'd want to change to an SMG class.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can change between the 4 classes (Assault, Engineer, Recon, and Support) whenever you are dead and waiting to spawn.

Comment: You can also change classes on supply crates dropped by your commander.

Comment: and at this point, you can change weapons, equipment etc.

Answer (score 3):

There are classes in Battlefield, but they're not the same as in Call of Duty. There are only four, they are somewhat predefined, and with more limited customization than in CoD.

Yes, you can change classes during a match each time you die. You can also edit the class loadouts during a match, changing things like your primary weapon or your attachments.

You can find more information on the classes in various locations, like [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-4/Classes).

Comment: As santyclause explained, I only have four class slots, and each can only hold one type of gun, as in I can't have 4 sniper class slots?

Comment: I seem to recall some ability to equip guns unlocked with other classes in other Battlefield games, but I haven't played them nearly as much as CoD games. It's at least possible that you could eventually unlock the ability to equip marksman rifles unlocked with the Recon class on your Engineer class, but I'm not certain if you can or not. No matter what, you always have an Assault, Engineer, Recon, and Support class.